# All .cmd files open with Notepad

Tags: windows, batch-file

All of my .cmd files open with notepad. How can I run it normally? I have already tried to remove its default value (in FileExts) in regedit.

Comment: this should be part of superuser .. any way go to control panel -> default programs = > set associations and set .cmd to the program u like..

Comment: @vishal no, this is not possible, the entry is locked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you should do.

1. Take registry backup.
2. Now go to registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.cmd` and delete entry below it.

PS
If the change does not work immediately, you might have to reboot.

Comment: Thanks, this solution solved my issue. For `.cmd` files I had to delete the `.cmd` entry, not the `.bat` one which was originally suggested.

Comment: In my Windows 8.1 there is no `.cmd` entry and the `.bat` entry may have been correct after all.

Comment: @Lokesh This didn't work for me even after restarting the system. The registry key has been deleted but the associations was the same. I had to do the change from "Control Panel" -> "Default Programs" as already suggested.